# OSX Terminal Tabs/Windows

Tags: macos, terminal

I have been searching for this for a while now and finally I give up and need to ask the question.

I have Terminal.app on my OSX (10.8.4) machine setup to remember my open terminal tabs & windows. This means that when I open the application my previously open tabs & widnows are restored with their working directories preserved.

So, if I have a session with tabs:

1. /usr/local
2. ~/github/project
3. ~/Documents

Upon closing and restarting the Terminal application those tabs will be restored on application startup.

I do not have a .bashrc file in my user directory or any window groups save in Terminal Preferences > Window Groups. Here are my settings for Terminal Preferences > Startup:

- On startup, open:

  - the radio button for "New window with settings:" is selected with "Pro"
- Shells open with:

  - Default login shell
- New windows open with:

  - Default Settings
  - Default Working Directory
- New tabs open with:

  - Default Settings
  - Same Working Directory

I am pretty sure I have not done any other customizing in the preferences for Terminal other than window size. Is there some other place that settings are being stored? I only ask because I sometimes use other computers and would like to bring this functionality with me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have found the answer due to rubber duck debugging with my friend @artlogic on Twitter. The problem (or solution, however you choose to see it) was in System Preferences > General, the option "Close window when quitting an application" was checked and therefore closing the windows before quitting the application thus nullifying the effect I was hoping for.

That is all.

Comment: A thousand times, yes!

Comment: Thanks! This should be configurable through Terminal itself and not some obscure "General" settings!

Comment: For clarity, this isn't Preferences Terminal, but the System Preferences app. I read in incorrectly a few times before realizing this.